# Perl Dancer after hook

Tags: perl, hook, dancer

Is there a way in Dancer to execute a code after every request?

I tried with an after hook but it seems that it doesn't execute after a file request...
There is a hook called 'after_file_render' which is executed a decent number of times after each request but I am not sure what is its purpose. Is it always called after every request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `after_file_render` hook is run after each successful request for a static file (e.g., a CSS file or an image), while the `after` hook runs after an action is performed by a route handler.

If you want to run the same code for both `after` and `after_file_render`, you can put it in a subroutine and assign it to the two hooks using a reference, e.g.:

```
sub foo {
    ...
}

hook after_file_render => \&foo;
hook after => \&foo;
```